# KNN Predictions return lesser rows than Training Data rows

Tags: r, prediction, knn

I am creating predictions from a training set of data that has 207 rows, but the predictions returned are of 90 rows. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. Can someone please point out where I am going wrong here?

```
# Fit the model 
knn_optimal <-  kknn(HeartDisease~., 
                 train = heart_training, 
                 test = heart_test,
                 k = 33, distance = 2)
knn_optimal

#For Class:
knn_pred_0.5=predict(knn_optimal, heart_training, type="raw", cutoff=0.5)
knn_pred_0.5

View(as.data.frame(knn_pred_0.5))

#For PP:
knn_predpp=predict(knn_optimal, heart_training, type="prob", cutoff=0.5)
knn_predpp


View(as.data.frame(knn_predpp))

# Create results data frame with training data
knn_training_results <- data.frame(heart_training, knn_pred_0.5, knn_predpp)

# Check results
knn_training_results %>% slice(1:5)
```

Comment: When you gave it the argument `test=heart_test` you told it to apply knn to the data heart_test not the training data. Presumably, heart_test has 90 rows.

Comment: @G5W yes you are right. I changed it to test=heart_training and it returned the same no. of rows. Thank you!